# FCGI+Perl+lighttpd: POST request is empty

Tags: perl, post, request, lighttpd, fastcgi

I have lighttpd server with fastcgi on perl.
Lighttpd configuration:

```
server.modules = (
        "mod_access",
        "mod_alias",
        "mod_compress",
        "mod_redirect",
        "mod_rewrite",
        "mod_accesslog",
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"

server.max-keep-alive-requests = 10
server.max-keep-alive-idle = 5
#server.max-fds = 10240
server.max-connections = 8192

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html",
                                "index.htm", "default.htm",
                                "index.lighttpd.html" )

url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )

static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

dir-listing.encoding        = "utf-8"
server.dir-listing          = "disable"

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/x-javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"

$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)hostname\.net$" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/hostname.net"
    url.rewrite-once = (     
        "^/index.php" => "/index.pl",
    )
}
```

Fast CGI is enabled. Here configuration fcgi.server:

```
fastcgi.server += ( ".pl" =>
        ((
                "socket" => "/tmp/perl.socket" + var.PID,
                "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/dispatch.fcgi",
                "docroot" => "/var/www/hostname.net",
                "check-local"     => "disable",
        ))
)
```

dispatch.fcgi:

```
use strict;
use CGI::Fast;
use Embed::Persistent; {
    my $p = Embed::Persistent->new();
    while (new CGI::Fast) {

        my $filename = $ENV{SCRIPT_FILENAME};
        my $package  = $p->valid_package_name($filename);
        my $mtime;

        if ($p->cached($filename, $package, \$mtime)) {

            eval {$package->handler;};
        }
        else {

            $p->eval_file($ENV{SCRIPT_FILENAME});
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my script (after editing):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
my $q = new CGI;

open my $fh, '>', "/var/www/hostname.net/payload.body" or die "Can't open payload.body: $!";
{
 local $/;
 print $fh $q->param('arg1');
}
close $fh;

print $q->header;
print $q->param('arg1');
```

Send request:

```
wget --post-data="arg1=dfsdfasf&arg2=sdfasfdsdf" http://hostname.net/test.pl --save-headers --quiet -O -
```

payload.body is empty(but time of change updates) and dump is:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri, 05 Oct 2012 12:23:07 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.28
```

That's all.

I tried get POST parameters by this way, but query comes empty. I so tried this way:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $request;
use FCGI;
my $env;
my $q = FCGI::Request();
$env = $q->GetEnvironment();
my $buffer = "data\n";

if ( $ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST" ){

    read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
}
else {

    print ("some error");
};

print("Content-type: text/plain\r\n\r\n", Dumper($buffer),"\n");
```

I need to get POST parameters from request (binary post data).

Can you help me? Maybe i take post parameters by wrong way?

Many thanks!

Comment: can you share the complete dump of output it cannot be only $VAR1 = ''

Comment: i added dump from first script: there is empty string and headers only

Answer (score 2):

#### `open` explained

Here is why your first script won't work:

```
open FH, "<payload.body";
#         ^---
```

perl borrows the `open` syntax from the Bourne Shell.

> `<`  means reading
>   `>`  means writing
>   `>>` means appending
>   `+<` means reading and writing

If we follow some best practices, your `open` statement would then be:

```
open my $fh, '>', "payload.body" or die "Can't open payload.body: $!";
```

#### Get Perl to help you

In fact, you were trying to `print` to a filehandle that was *read-only*. However, Perl can warn you about this and many other issues you might run into. Just `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of the script (actually *all* of your scripts). You can issue better error messages with the `Carp` module. Please note that on a server, these warning usually go into a log, but what you find there is worth finding.

#### What `Dumper` is

The `Data::Dumper` module takes Perl data structures and turns them into executable Perl code. This is great for debugging, sometimes OK for serialization, but never good to just print out a string or scalar. All contained data will be quoted in order to be valid Perl, which is not what you want.

#### Other bits and pieces

`read` starts to fill the target variable from the beginning (index 0). Specify an offset as 4th argument (e.g. `-1`) to append the data you are reading.

`binmode` without a second argument is only useful on Windows.
On Windows, `\n` can be a logical newline (e.g. "`\r\n`"). Use the byte values `\015\012` in networking.

In your second example, you overwrite `$buffer` with `$ENV{CONTENT_LENGTH}` characters from `STDIN`. You might want to print this content length out as well for debug purposes.

`FCGI::Request()` returns a request object. The [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/FCGI-0.74/FCGI.PL) states that you have to `Accept` each request, probably in a loop. The `Accept` method returns a value `>= 0` in case of success.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed typos and edited my question accordingly. But output is still empty :( I have not yet corrected second script.